# Nested parent data value according to child's data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get value from anchor attribute (parent `data-dir_r`) according to anchor (child `data-dir_r`). Its returning `null` all the time.

Here is my html and jQuery ::

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<ul class="ul-element">

 <li class="li-element">
    <a class="anchor" href="#" data-dir_r="143"> Parent</a>

    <ul class="ul-element">

        <li class="li-element">

            <a class="anchor" href="#" data-dir_r="100"> Child </a>

        </li>

    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="click-here"> Click here </a>

<script>

$("a.click-here").click(function(event){

    var number = 100;

    var child = $("ul li a.anchor").filter("[data-dir_r='" + number + "']");
    var prent = child.find("li a.anchor").data("dir_r");

    console.log(prent);

});

</script>
```

Requirement :

1. when I click on the anchor `Click here` then it will match child `data-dir_r=100` in the list
2. according to `data-dir_r=100` it will find parent upper (parent li anchor) anchor `data-dir_r` value
3. Output will be `143`

Error:

1. now its returning null

**[jsFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/selimppc/r0apgabe/)**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use `closest()` or `parents()` instead of `find` in :

```
var prent = child.find("li a.anchor").data("dir_r");
```

And give you `li` parent a class (`parent` in my example), so it should be :

```
var prent = child.closest("li.parent").find('a.anchor').data("dir_r");
//Or
var prent = child.parents("li.parent").find('a.anchor').data("dir_r");
```

So it will go up from the `child` to the parent `li a.anchor` then get the data desired.

**NOTE :** If you don't want or you can't add class you could use :

```
var prent = child.closest("ul:first>li").find('a.anchor').data("dir_r");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("a.click-here").click(function(event){
  var number = 100;
  var child = $("ul li a.anchor").filter("[data-dir_r='" + number + "']");
  var prent = child.closest("li.parent").find('a.anchor').data("dir_r");
  
  console.log(prent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ul-element">

  <li class="li-element parent">
    <a class="anchor" href="#" data-dir_r="143"> Parent</a>

    <ul class="ul-element">

      <li class="li-element">

        <a class="anchor" href="#" data-dir_r="100"> Child </a>

     </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="click-here"> Click here </a>
```

Comment: its returning `100` instead of `143` .. its not getting for parent data value

Comment: :: its working now .. thank you so much . Was it for `jquery.min.js` ??